# Mathematics involved in string theory

Tags: string-theory, education, mathematics

As an amateur mathematician and lover of the sciences I have a well working knowledge of classical mechanics, quantum mechanics, general relativity, quantization, and so on...  But recently I've been intrigued in the concept of string theory and have considered reading Polchinski's text book on the matter. As a lover of mathematics first most are there any different branches of mathematics used in proofs in string theory other then the types of mathematics used in the subjects I have listed above?

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/195041/2451