# Mathematical prerequisites for M-theory

Tags: string-theory, education, models, branes, theory-of-everything

I am interested in learning M-theory; however I have no Idea as to what mathematics is required for it. Are the prerequisites the same as string theory? Is there more mathematical knowledge needed for M-theory?

Comment: The prerequisite *is* string theory.

Comment: @aygx The bulk of of knowledge known as "M-theory" is immense, therefore the answer strongly depends on what exactly do you want to learn or investigate about M-theory. If you refine your question the community could help in a much more informed way.

Comment: Apparently all you need to know is what a superpoint is. :-)   https://ncatlab.org/schreiber/show/M-Theory+from+the+Superpoint

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/195041/2451