# Knowledge pre-requisite on mathematics and physics in order to study string theory

Tags: string-theory

I would like to study string-theory on my own and would like to know the knowledge pre-requisite on mathematics and physics I should master before embarking on my journey to study string theory.

Thanks

Comment: What's your current level of knowledge?

Comment: @Prof.Legolasov For mathematics, it would be similar to an undergraduate engineering degree. For physics, I had taken a course in classical mechanics (Physics 1), electro-magnetism (Physics 2). Engineering thermal dynamics. For modern physics, I had touched on the Photoelectric Effect, light behaving as particles and waves and a bit on Quantum mechanics and the 4 quantum numbers without going too details into the schrodinger equation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Introduction to string theory](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/29007/introduction-to-string-theory)

Comment: Also [Mathematics needed for string theory](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/195041/mathematics-needed-for-string-theory)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best thing is to get a book on String Theory such as  Kiritsis' "String Theory in a Nutshell" (About $30 from Amazon) and look at what math is used/needed  there. Then get suitable books to fill in the gaps in  what you already know.